# Property reflection to attribute broken on canary?

Tags: polymer

It was my understanding after reading this www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#attrreflection (sorry, not allowed to include more than two links), that *Property values are reflected back into their attribute counterpart*

That doesn't look to be the case in 37.0.2007.2 canary with experimental Web Platform features enabled.

For instance, have a look at the console http://jsbin.com/fihan/2/edit

Another example is in [Eric's Bidelman video](http://youtu.be/3QLmAm9xtnU?t=19m50s) at 19min 58s:
I would expect the Element panel to update `<demo-tab selected="0">` to `<demo-tab selected="1">`

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recent change on the Polymer side (not Chrome) where property values are no longer reflected back to their attribute value. It's now opt-in for perf. You need to use the `publish` block with `reflect: true`:

```
publish: {
  foo: {value: 'foo', reflect: true}
}
```

http://jsbin.com/qavavina/1/edit

We have yet to get the documented :( https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/402

Comment: Is there a way to have also reflection with object ?
The serialized attribute will get reflected in the parsed property, but if I set the property it won't be serialized back in the attribute. [http://jsbin.com/wikob/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/wikob/1/edit)